# What is the scheme name for identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity, .net-core-authorization

Let's say I use the following:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, UserRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

What is the authentication scheme name being set? I didn't find this in any documentation. I tried looking for a class with the names `IdentityAuthenticationDefaults` and `IdentityDefaults` but found nothing. I have tried "Cookies" but it isn't set to this. The application works well, so there is surely some scheme name set.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`IdentityConstants`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityConstants.cs) is the class you're looking for here. Here's the relevant part for your specific question (xmldocs removed):

```
public class IdentityConstants
{
    private static readonly string CookiePrefix = "Identity";

    public static readonly string ApplicationScheme = CookiePrefix + ".Application";

    ...
}
```

`IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme` is used as the `DefaultAuthenticateScheme` - the value itself ends up being **`Identity.Application`**.

The schemes get set up [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L47):

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
})
```

Here are links to the API reference docs:

- [`IdentityConstants`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityconstants?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [`IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityconstants.applicationscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: thanks, it solves the issue. However, since this isn't a constant, any ideas on how to use it `Authorize` without hardcoding Identity.Application? I guess creating a custom auth scheme would be a long way of doing it.

Comment: A custom policy should fit for that - see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2x#selecting-the-scheme-with-policies) for how that would work.

Answer (score 3):

Silly that there are static string references under IdentityConstants but these are not usable by the AuthorizeAttribute class or method attribute to set the AuthenticationSchemes property since it must be a constant value. I created a simple shared constants class that contains the necessary to get around this but wish MS provided something OOTB.

```
public class SharedConstants
{
    public const string IdentityApplicationScheme = "Identity.Application";
}
```

Then you can use it like this.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = SharedConstants.IdentityApplicationScheme)]
```